# Disabling JRebel without restarting

Tags: java, jrebel

Is it possible to disable JRebel dynamically, without restarting the Java process?

It would be useful as sometimes I want to make changes to the code (and compile it) on a system that is being shared, without those changes becoming "live" yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. JRebel instruments the code at the class loading phase. For disabling it, it would require to rollback *all* the instrumentation back to the initial state, which is not possible atm.